# How can I call a controller action from ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have this method in my reports_controller.rb, which allows an user to send a status.

```
def send_status        
  date = Date.today        
  reports = current_user.reports.for_date(date)        
  ReportMailer.status_email(current_user, reports, date).deliver        
  head :ok      
  rescue => e        
  head :bad_request    
end
```

How can I call this action from ActiveAdmin, in order to check if a User sent this report or not? I want it like a status_tag on a column or something.
Should I do a member action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'll address the issue of checking if a report has been sent later, but first I'll cover the question of how to call the controller action from ActiveAdmin.

While you can call `ReportsController#send_status` by creating an `ActionController::Base::ReportsController` and then calling the desired method, e.g.

```
ActionController::Base::ReportsController.new.send_status
```

this isn't a good idea. You probably should refactor this to address a couple potential issues.

`app/controllers/reports_controller.rb`:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  ... # rest of controller methods

  def send_status
    if current_user # or whatever your conditional is
      ReportMailer.status_email(current_user).deliver
      response = :ok
    else
      response = :bad_request
    end

    head response
  end
end
```

`app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ... # rest of user model

  def reports_for_date(date)
    reports.for_date(date)
  end
end
```

`app/mailers/reports_mailer.rb`

```
class ReportsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  ... # rest of mailer

  def status_email(user)
    @user = user
    @date = Date.today
    @reports = @user.reports_for_date(@date)

    ... # rest of method        
  end
end
```

This could obviously be refactored further, but provides a decent starting point.

An important thing to consider is that this controller action is not sending the email asynchronously, so in the interest of concurrency and user experience, you should strongly consider using a queuing system. DelayedJob would be an easy implementation with the example I've provided (look into the DelayedJob RailsCast).

As far as checking if the report has been sent, you could implement an ActionMailer Observer and register that observer:

*This requires that the `User` model have a BOOLEAN column `status_sent` and that users have unique email address.*

`lib/status_sent_mail_observer.rb`:

```
class StatusSentMailObserver
  self.delivered_email(message)
    user = User.find_by_email(message.to)
    user.update_attribute(:status_sent, true)
  end
end
```

`config/intializer/setup_mail.rb`:

```
... # rest of initializer
Mail.register_observer(StatusSentMailObserver)
```

If you are using DelayedJob (or almost any other queuing system) you could implement a callback method to be called on job completion (i.e. sending the status email) that updates a column on the user.

If you want to track the status message for every day, you should consider creating a `Status` model that belongs to the `User`. The status model could be created every time the user sends the email, allowing you to check if the email has been sent simply by checking if a status record exists. This strategy is one I would seriously consider adopting over just a simple `status_sent` column.

**tl;dr** `ActionController::Base::ReportsController.new.send_status` & implement an observer that updates a column on the user that tracks the status. But you really don't want to do that. Look into refactoring like I've mentioned above.

Comment: Instead of having that method in the User model, I have it in the Report model :def self.for_date(date=nil)
               date ||= Date.today
               where(:date => date.to_time)
              end                                                                   but I guess I will just adapt the mail observer for reports.I am also using delayed jobs.Thanks!

Comment: The reason I added it to `User` is to follow the principle of least knowledge (Law of Demeter). The object asking for the user's reports for a given day shouldn't know how the user is getting those reports (makes for much easier refactoring & testing).