# Execute controller action from ActiveAdmin panel using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, activeadmin

I have **Rails 4** and **ActiveAdmin** plugin.

In advertisement controller I have 3 methods. Bassicaly I want to add admin function to extend advertisement expire date. There are three options:

```
 def add_two_weeks(advertisement)
   @advertisement = advertisement
     @advertisement.expiration = @advertisement.expiration + 14.days                    
          @advertisement.save 
 end

 def add_eight_weeks(advertisement)
     @advertisement = advertisement
       @advertisement.expiration = @advertisement.expiration + 56.days                    
          @advertisement.save 
 end

 def add_max_weeks(advertisement)
      @advertisement = advertisement
       @advertisement.expiration = @advertisement.expiration + 168.days                    
          @advertisement.save 
 end
```

In **admin/advertisement.rb**

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Advertisement do
  scope :all, default: true


  scope :blacklisted do |advertisements|
    advertisements.where("in_blacklist= ?", true).where("admin_confirmed= ?", true)
  end

  scope :waiting_to_blacklist do |advertisements|
    advertisements.where("in_blacklist= ?", true)
  end

  scope :paid do |advertisements|
    advertisements.where("paid= ?", true)
  end




index :as => :grid do |product|
    div do
      a :href => admin_advertisement_path(advertisement) do
        image_tag(advertisement.photo.url(:thumb))
      end
    end
    a truncate(advertisement.name), :href => admin_advertisement_path(advertisement)
  end


  index do
    column :name
    column "Price", sortable: :price do |advertisement|
       advertisement.price
    end
    default_actions
  end


 form do |f|
   f.inputs 'User data' do
         f.input :name
         f.input :email
         f.input :country
         f.input :description
         f.input :description_ru

   end 

     f.inputs 'Additional data' do
         f.input :expiration
         f.input :highlight
         f.input :recomend
         f.input :vip_highlight
         f.input :vip_recomend
   end


  f.inputs 'Blacklist (Information: Both checkboxes need to be checked to blacklist user! )' do

         f.input :in_blacklist
         f.input :admin_confirmed
   end 

   f.inputs 'Change password' do
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
  end
  f.actions
end


 show do
   member_action do
        link_to "add 2 weeks", advertisements_add_two_weeks_path(advertisement)
     end

     panel "Recent Reviews" do

          table_for advertisement.reviews.each do |review|
             column(:user)    {|review| link_to(review.user.name, admin_user_path(review.user)) }
             column(:content)    {|review| review.content}
             column("Created at")   {|review| review.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M")                      }

          end

      end

  end

  sidebar :advertisement_information, :only => :show do
    attributes_table_for advertisement do

      row("User") { auto_link advertisement.name }
      row :email
      row :in_blacklist
      row :admin_confirmed
      row :created_at
    end
  end

  permit_params :name, :email, :country_id, :in_blacklist, :admin_confirmed, :password, :password_confirmation


end
```

**Error**: undefined method `member_action'

I took ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491443/how-can-i-call-a-controller-action-from-activeadmin), but can't understand principle of this. So I improvised.

I can't figure out if this is the way to do such things or I need completely different aproach ? Am newbie in ActiveAdmin modification, please be kind.

Any  help will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show full `admin/advertisement.rb`.

Comment: block with `member_action` should be executing inside `ActiveAdmin::Views::ActionItems` instance.

Comment: @Зелёный thanks, for that, but my principle of doing this is in right direction ? I mean all controller stuff and etc ? tnx again

Comment: Look at answer below it is describe totally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, member_action means `Do operation with single record from perticular one row` and collection_action means `Do operation with all records`.

You can write member_action like this:

```
member_action :send_push_notification do
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to :action => :show
end
```

If you need perticular link(In image I have changed link to button with css) besides view, edit, delete like this:

[image]

Then use this:

```
actions defaults: true do |gift|
    link_to 'Send Push Notification', send_push_notification_path
end
```

For link action path create one def(here: send_push_notification) into controller and from there redirect to admin.

Let me know if you need more.

Comment: tnx. how does the link action path looks like ? How does that redirect looks like ?

Comment: link_action path means `send_push_notification_path` and redirect looks like `redirect_to admin_user_path, :notice => t(:push_notification_sent_to_all_user)`

Comment: With controller you mean Active Admin controller ? or usual one ?

Comment: Can you paste full error? and also let me know how you call link?